# Deploying SQL Database changes from a SSDT project

Tags: sql-server, deployment, sql-server-data-tools

I have a Visual Studio SSDT project which I use to keep track of all database changes and it is all kept under source control.

From Visual Studio I can deploy this to my local SQL Server and also our test environment. However I can not remotely connect to our Production SQL Server for security reasons but I can RDP into the production server.

What is the best way to ensure all my database changes get deployed to production?

Not sure it makes much difference for this question but I am using VS 2015 and SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I think you will need access to production environment, otherwise how else you expect to deploy these changes to that environment. As far as "security" is concerned, you have perfectly valid reason to have access to prod environment, I would suggest you to speak to your dba.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate a DACPAC on the production environment and then copy that DACPAC over to your development environment.  From there, you can use SSDT to compare what is in source control with what is in the DACPAC and generate DDL scripts that will bring your production database in sync with source control.

Comment: I'd also version a "Publish Profile" that's for production so you can use that to push the changes in the right manner when it hits production.  Copy the dacpac + the publish profile, run that through SQLPackage and you should be good. There's even a NuGet package for SSDT bits now if that's a concern, though you're probably better off having some sort of build box that can handle all of the publishing work. Install SSDT on that box.  That box's service account could also have access to make the appropriate changes or the DBA team can kick them off.